# Google Maps API v3 drawingManager delete all

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have 2 button (images). The first will delete only selected shape (and it works). And the second must delete all overlays on the map (and I cant underatand how do it).

I sure that mistakes here:

```
 var line = e;
line.type = e.type;
```

But I dont have any ideas how do it.
Which variable stores the array of polylines?

Thanks!

```
  function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
  }
    function deleteSelectedShape() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setMap(null);
    }
  }
  .......   
  function deleteAllShape(newPolygon) {
     if (newPolygon) {
         for (i in newPolygon) {
            newPolygon[i].setMap(null);
        }
         newPolygon.length = 0;
         }
      }
..........
drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
.......});


 google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
         var line = e;
         line.type = e.type;
         var newShape = e.overlay;
         newShape.type = e.type;

        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);


        google.maps.event.addListener(line, 'polylinecomplete', function() {
        deleteAllShape(line);
    });
      }


    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete all the shape after draw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004550/how-to-delete-all-the-shape-after-draw)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing polygon from google maps drawingManager V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632402/removing-polygon-from-google-maps-drawingmanager-v3)