# How to remove the newly created rectangle without removing the previous rectangles in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a simple map application (draw rectangle) using google maps. I have a Save button, when I draw a rectangle I save its coordinates. I also have Clear button that would only clear the unsaved rectangles. How do I work the Clear button where I will only remove the newly created rectangles? I worked with "rectangle.setMap(null)" but it seems that it removes all the rectangles (including the saved ones). Any help would be great!

Thanks.

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 10.487, lng: 123.975},
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
      },
      rectangleOptions: {
          fillColor: '#00FF00',
          strokeColor: "red",
          strokeWeight: 2,
          clickable: true,
          editable: true,
          draggable:true,
          zIndex: 1,
      }

  });

  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', function(rectangle) {
    drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

    drawingManager.setOptions({
      drawingControl: false //after drawing you cannot draw again, so you have to save it first
    });

    $("#btnSave").on('click', function(){
      drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingControl: true
      });
    });

    $("#btnClear").on('click', function(){ //when clicking Clear the saved rectangle must not be removed, only the newly created/unsaved rects
      rectangle.setMap(null); //
      drawingManager.setOptions({
        drawingControl: true
      });
    });


    document.getElementById("north_east").value = rectangle.getBounds().getNorthEast();
    document.getElementById("south_west").value = rectangle.getBounds().getSouthWest();

    
  });
}
```

Comment: You simply must set null the object you want delete. However show your code, is more easy evaluete you problem .

Comment: I haven't really worked on the Clear button just yet.  $("#btnClear").on('click', function(){
      rectangle.setMap(null);
I only have this line. I'm new to google maps and js so I have know idea yet

Comment: this code is only a part of what is useful. Show the code where you create the rectangle and store the object.Please edit your question and format the code properly.

Comment: I have added the code, your comments will be a great help thanks

Comment: Is not easy with drawing manager i think could be useful this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632402/removing-polygon-from-google-maps-drawingmanager-v3