# How to clear a map from GoogleMaps API with a button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I have recently integrated drawing functions in a website. But I want to be able to clear the map without having to recharge the whole page.

I followed this great example about [Custom Controls](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) in order to add a well-integrated button that react on click.

Also, I read the [DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) documentation, there is several options you can play with, but nothing about clearing a map.

Based on the *Custom Controls* example, I would like to do something like that:

```
    controlUI.addEventListener('click', function() {
      clearMap();
    });
```

But I don't know how to get an array of drawn objects in order to erase them.

Comment: Related question: [Removing polygon from google maps drawingManager V3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632402/removing-polygon-from-google-maps-drawingmanager-v3)

Comment: I guess I just type wrong keywords. But anyway, I think that my answer is more generic and detailed, that's mainly why I wanted to ask and answer this question, because it can be useful for others. But maybe I was wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find an array of drawn objects, you can at least create one.
At the bottom of the link that you provided, there is something helpful about [Drawing Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer#drawing_events).

So if you want to clear the map with a custom control, the idea is to hold a list of these objects since they are created. For example, with circles and rectangles:

First hold a global array of desired objects (here, circles and rectangles):

```
var circles = [];
var rectangles = [];
```

Then initialize your map (it needs to be done **BEFORE** adding the drawing API):

```
function initMap(){
  // Your initializations
  initDrawings();
}
```

Then, init your DrawingManager as desire and add event listeners. Don't forget to add the control button:

```
function initDrawings(){
  drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    drawingMode: null,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      drawingModes: ['circle', 'rectangle']
    },
    markerOptions: {icon: '/path/to/icon.png'},
    circleOptions: {
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 0.25,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      zIndex: 1
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', updateDrawings);
  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'rectanglecomplete', updateDrawings);
  drawingManager.setMap(map);

  var eraseControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var eraseControl = new EraseButton(eraseControlDiv,map);

  eraseControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(eraseControlDiv);
}

function EraseButton(controlDiv, map) {
  var controlUI = document.createElement('div');
  controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  controlUI.style.border = '2px solid #fff';
  controlUI.style.borderRadius = '3px';
  controlUI.style.boxShadow = '0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3)';
  controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlUI.style.marginBottom = '20px';
  controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlUI.title = 'Click to clear map';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

  var controlText = document.createElement('div');
  controlText.style.color = 'rgb(25,25,25)';
  controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Roboto,Arial,sans-serif';
  controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
  controlText.style.lineHeight = '38px';
  controlText.style.paddingLeft = '5px';
  controlText.style.paddingRight = '5px';
  controlText.innerHTML = 'Empty Map';
  controlUI.appendChild(controlText);

  controlUI.addEventListener('click', emptyMap);

}
```

Here is the function that check the [shape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes) of the object that triggered a *shapecomplete* event. It just adds an element in the corresponding array.

```
function updateDrawings(shape){
  if(shape == null) return;

  if(shape instanceof google.maps.Circle){
    circles.push(shape);
  }
  else if (shape instanceof google.maps.Rectangle) {
    rectangles.push(shape);
  }
}
```

And here, we set these elements out of the map, and we clear each list.

```
function emptyMap(){
  circles.forEach(function(e){
    e.setMap(null);
  });
  rectangles.forEach(function(e){
    e.setMap(null);
  });
  circles = [];
  rectangles = [];
}
```